# Algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, class-field-theory

Is there an example of a field $E$ which is not algebraically closed but each finite simple field extension $K$ of $E$, is isomorphic (not necessarily is identity over $E$) as a field to $E$?

Comment: Note that there exists a field $E$ such that a finite simple extension of $E$ is isomorphic to $E$. For example if $F$ is a field and $x$ is a variable over $F$, then take $E=F(x^2)$, then $E(x)$ is isomorphic to $E$.

Comment: I know that for $E = \mathbf{C}$ there is a proof with Galois-theory which uses exactly the idea that every finite extension of $\mathbf{C}$ is equal to $\mathbf{C}$. However, it uses the intermediate theorem for $\mathbf{R}$ and another fact which is not necessarily true for arbitrary fields. The problem with an arbitrary field $E$ is that an isomorphism $E \to K$ doesn't have do be an $E$-isomorphism (of vector spaces over $E$). If this were the case, then every such field would be algebraically closed, because you would have that $K= E$.

Comment: I’m not sure, but what about $\mathbb{C}((x))$?

Answer (score 4):

Let $K=\mathbb{C}((x))$. Let $L/K$ be a finite extension. Since $K$ is a non-Archimedian complete discretely valued field, there is a unique extension of the absolute value on $K$ to $L$.

Since the residue field of $K$ is algebraically closed, $L/K$ is totally ramified.

Let $\varpi$ be a uniformizer of $L$, then $\varpi^e \in xO_L^{\times}$, where $e=[L:K]$.

By Hensel’s lemma, $u\in O_L^{\times} \longmapsto u^e \in O_L^{\times}$ is onto, so we can choose $\varpi$ such that $\varpi^e=x$.

It’s easy to show that $O_L=O_K[\varpi]$, so the above shows that $L=\mathbb{C}((x^{1/e})) \cong \mathbb{C}((x)) = K$.